# reference value of map type field in mongo using spring data (dbref)

Tags: java, mongodb, dictionary, spring-data, dbref

I have a map field in my document (key = content type, value = content) where I want the value part(content, which is another document) to be saved in mongodb as a referenced object.

```
private Map<ContentType, Content> relatedContents;
```

For example, for a content type, "CONTENT_TYPE_X", it should save like

> "relatedContents" : { "CONTENT_TYPE_X" : DBRef("content", ObjectId("51ea2c0167e855d6b3d3dda3") }

For a normal field reference can be achieved using `@DBREF` , eg.

```
@DBRef
private Content content;
```

But of course it doesn't work in this case by just putting `@DBRef` , is it somehow possible to achieve what I am saying?

```
@DBRef
private Map<ContentType, Content> relatedContents;
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it exactly as you propose with spring-data-mongodb version 1.3 M1 or later:

```
@DBRef
private Map<String, Content> relatedContents;
```

see [DATAMONGO-657](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-657)